# Iterare through background images

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to make a dynamically background that changes images every x seconds. But i want the images to be sourced from a directory in a django project. I have this piece of code but is hardcoded and limited.

```
var header = $('body');

var backgrounds = new Array(
    'url(static/media/backgrounds/1.jpg)'
  , 'url(static/media/backgrounds/2.jpg)'
  , 'url(static/media/backgrounds/3.jpg)'
  , 'url(static/media/backgrounds/4.jpg)'
  , 'url(static/media/backgrounds/5.jpg)'
  , 'url(static/media/backgrounds/6.jpg)'
  , 'url(static/media/backgrounds/7.jpg)'
  , 'url(static/media/backgrounds/8.jpg)'
  , 'url(static/media/backgrounds/9.jpg)'
  , 'url(static/media/backgrounds/10.jpg)'
);

var current = 0;

function nextBackground() {
    current++;
    current = current % backgrounds.length;
    header.css('background-image', backgrounds[current]);
}
setInterval(nextBackground, 5000);

header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);
```

Comment: last line shows that you are only using the first background image `header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);`

Comment: `header.css('background-image', backgrounds[0]);`. remove this line.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you'll need to enumerate the images you want. For simple deployments, where static files will be on your filesystem (in `STATIC_ROOT`) and served from under `/static/`, something like

```
# Get absolute disk paths of files
backgrounds = glob.glob(os.path.join(settings.STATIC_ROOT, 'media', 'backgrounds', '*.jpg'))
# Turn into URLs
background_urls = [f'/static/media/backgrounds/{os.path.basename(bg)}' for bg in backgrounds]
```

will do; for a more robust solution, you'd probably want to use the [staticfiles finders API](https://github.com/django/django/blob/ae8338daf34fd746771e0678081999b656177bae/django/contrib/staticfiles/finders.py#L280) to enumerate all files and turn them into URLs.

For serving that data to your view, a couple of options I can think of.

## List the backgrounds in your view and pass the array into the template

- Enumerate all of the background images' URLs into a list, pass it to the template
- Render it into a JSON list: `{{ background_urls|json_script:"backgrounds" }}`

## View returning Javascript fragment

- Wire up a view that returns a JavaScript fragment with all the background URLs, e.g. `var backgrounds = ["/static/foo.jpg"];`
- Use that in your view: `<script src="{% url "background_list_js" %}"></script>`
- Your script would otherwise work as-is

## View returning JSON payload

- Wire up a view that returns a JSON object with all the background URLs, e.g. `["/static/foo.jpg"]`
- Use e.g. `fetch()` or another AJAX method to load the data before starting to change backgrounds

## View returning a random background URL

- Wire up a view that returns a JSON object with a single random background URL from the selection, e.g. `{"url": "/static/foo.jpg"}`
- Use e.g. `fetch()` or another AJAX method to load the data every time you need a new background.

## Custom template tag returning a Javascript fragment

- Like option 1, but instead of having a separate view, register a [simple template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) you can then use to inline the background array: `<script>{% dump_backgrounds %}</script>`